# Copy Favorites from list of machines to another list of machines

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So here's what i'm trying to do:
Lets say i have 20 machines that im replacing, but each machine is locked down so that they can only save favorites. So i only have to copy the favorites folder over to the new machines.

I'm pretty sure the command i need to run for each machine is like so:

> xcopy \\OldMachine\share\users\OldMachine\Favorites \\NewMachine\share\users\NewMachine\Favorites /s /y

And then just loop that over and over for each set of machines.

So my thought was I would need 2 txt files, newhosts.txt, and oldhosts.txt.

The user accounts are the same as the machine names.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is correct but can be made more bullet proof. Quotes allow it to work even if spaces are in the paths. Specifing wildcards makes your intent clear (see /I for another way).

```
xcopy "\\OldMachine\share\users\OldMachine\Favorites\*.*" "\\NewMachine\share\users\NewMachine\Favorites\*.*" /s /y
```

Put both source and destination paths into a textfile separated by a comma.

EG

```
\\OldMachine\share\users\OldMachine\Favorites,\\NewMachine\share\users\NewMachine\Favorites
\\OldMachine\share\users\OldMachine\Favorites,\\NewMachine\share\users\NewMachine\Favorites
\\OldMachine\share\users\OldMachine\Favorites,\\NewMachine\share\users\NewMachine\Favorites
```

Then type

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %A in ("C:\ComputerList.txt") do xcopy "%A\*.*" "%B\*.*" /s /y
```

In a batchfile replace `%A` and `%B` with `%%A` and `%%B`.

Type `xcopy /?` and `for /?` for help.